# Importing video from a videotape recorded on Sony Handycam

Tags: windows, video, camera, digitization

I used Windows Movie Maker to import videos from a videotape recorded on Sony handycam. I imported the video in .avi format( as it was giving the best video quality), but the size of the video is very large (8GB for just 1 hour). Moreover, it takes a lot of time to import the video in Windows Movie Maker (approx. 2.5 hrs. for 1 hour video).

Please suggest some other software which is more robust in the sense that it can give good quality video in lesser size and also it should be able to import the video quickly(as I have to import many video cassettes).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [virtualdub](http://www.virtualdub.org/). It is free and you can compress the video with the codecs you have installed on your pc.

Answer (score 0):

It would be pretty easy to convert the AVI file to a more compact format using many free programs, notably [VLC](http://videolan.org) and [mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu).  Both can also digitize video from tape, butI have no experience using them in this mode so I can't give advice or recommend them.

On the commercial side, I have had many good experiences using [Pinnacle Systems](http://www.pinnaclesys.com) equipment and software to digitize video, if you don't mind the proprietary nature of their hardware and software.